# How to use STL binary search operations with pairs?

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search, stl-algorithm

How to use STL binary search operations with pairs ? 
I also wish to use lower_bound function . Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

`std::pair` overloads the `operator<` thus any algorithm that uses ordering will work with pairs (assuming you've overloaded `operator<` for the pair members). The ordering is first by the `first` member and then by `second` if the `first` parts are equal. The `lower_bound` function that takes no predicate as argument uses the `operator<` for the comparison, thus it will work for pairs too.

Comment: Can you give sample illustration on how to implement it (lower_bound particularly), i am still not clear with it :)

Comment: If your question is how to overload the < operator, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/812912)

Comment: Hey i am not able to make it work , pair doesn't has iterators . Can you please provide a snippet on how to use lower_bound function on say pair<int,int> please?

Comment: A lower_bound is defined on a collection not an object. Maybe I misunderstood your question - what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm searching for pairs where (pair.first == foo) how do I state that as a val?